# Combining multiple regex capturing groups and get first match

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-group

I have multiple groups and I want to split the string on the first match, so the code looks like this:

```
regex_patterns = (
    r"(?P<group1>345)",
    r"(?P<group2>123)",
)
p = re.compile("|".join(regex_patterns))
p.split("012345", maxsplit=1)
```

this will output `["0", "123", None, "45"]`, so it will show `None` for `<group2>`. Is there a way to make this only output `["0", "123", "45"]` (i.e. ignore unmatched groups), and which group was matched?

Comment: When you split, you lose the names of the groups anyway. You must match the string if you plan to preserve the names alongside the matches.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want all the splits without `None`, and you want to know which group made the split happen. From that and your wording, I just assume that only a single group can be matched.

To get the group name, you have to perform another match, because `re.split` doesn't give you that. For example:

```
def custom_split(p, line):
    splits = re.split(p, line)

    match = re.search(p, line)
    for group, found in match.groupdict().items():
        if found is not None:
            return group, [s for s in splits if s is not None]

    return None, None

matched_group, splits = custom_split(p, "012345")
```

If you don't want to match twice, an alternative would be to only perform `re.search`, and then use the match positions (using `match.start()` and `len(found)`) to do the splitting yourself.

Answer (score 1):

re.split can keep what's split on, if it's in capture group.

But your combined regex contains multiple named capture groups.
So simplify it and create a combined regex that has only 1 capture group.

**Example snippet:**

```
import re

regex_patterns = (
    '345',
    '123'
)

regex_combined_pattern = '('+ '|'.join(regex_patterns) +')'
print(regex_combined_pattern)

str = '012345603456'

result = re.split(regex_combined_pattern, str)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
(345|123)
['0', '123', '4560', '345', '6']
```

Comment: This doesn't tell me which group was matched, but it solves the `None` issue.

Comment: @FrankVel Well, this does just cut the string up into an array.  But if the intention is to find which group(s) are in the string then I assume search() or findall() or even finditer() would be better for that.